# Integrating a simple exponential over the space of matrices that define a metric

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, st.statistics

I want to interpret an $n\times n$ matrix $D$ as a set of pairwise distances, and assume that $D$ obeys metric properties.  Namely, $D_{ii} = 0$, $D_{ij} \geq 0$, $D_{ij} = D_{ji}$ and $D_{ij} \leq D_{ik} + D_{kj}$ for all $1 \leq i,j,k \leq n$.  For convenience, let $\bigtriangleup_n$ denote the set of such matrices.

Now, I need to integrate some "simple" functions over this set.  The simplest would be an exponential.  Namely, I want to compute something like $\int_{\bigtriangleup_n} \exp\left[-\lambda \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i+1}^n D_{ij}\right] d D$.

I've been able to work this out for the simplest nontrivial case: namely $n=3$.  But for higher $n$, my brute force way of calculation gets really ugly.  The approach I've been taking is to basically first integrate over $D_{11}, D_{12}, D_{13}, ..., D_{1n}$, all of which have no constraints... then integrate over $D_{23}$ which is just a definite integral from $|D_{12} - D_{23}|$ to $D_{12}+D_{23}$ of $\exp[-\lambda D_{13}]$ and then, in the general case, integrating over $D_ij$ becomes the definite integral from $\max_{k \neq i,j} |D_{ik}-D_{jk}|$ to $\min_{k\neq i,j} D_{ik}+D_{jk}$, but this is the point at which I get stuck, because these things becomes nasty quite quickly (even for just $n=4$).

At the end of the day, I've love to be able to integrate more complex functions, like a chi-square type function rather than an exponential type function, but the exponential is the most trivial case that is interesting...

> To be precise, I'm looking for a closed form evaluation of the integral above, preferably with some derivation that will help me work out more complex examples.

Comment: Have you tried using Mathematica, Maple, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

The space of variables $D_{ij}$ satisfying the constraints of a metric form a polytope (or really a cone, since any scalar multiple satisfies it as well). In general, integrating functions over such objects can be (computationally) hard. [Here's an article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2083v3) that talks about this in more detail (for the specific case of integrating polynomials over a simplex).

Caveats:

- you're integrating over a cone, not a polytope: maybe that makes things easier (although I doubt it)
- you're integrating a very specific kind of function and maybe some specific tricks work for that case.
- if you're willing to get an approximate answer, I'd suspect that something might be possible

Comment: In fact all this boils down to finding volume of set $\sum D_{ij}=1$. It is nice convex polytope, with $n(n-1)(n-2)/2$ faces... BUT I do not see right a way what is it --- it might be complicated

Answer (score 1):

A keyword that comes to mind is "first-passage percolation on the complete graph of n vertices," though I don't know that anybody's studied this. FPP is the assignment of random lengths (or "passage times") to a graph. Typically, this is over the lattice $\mathbb Z^d$, rather than arbitrary graphs.  A major tool is the subadditive ergodic theorem, which relies on the fact that you can translate along the lattice; in the case of the complete graph, you would have no such tool.